# How to make it async in javascript or node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

```
var responseArr = new Array();
async.each(response, function (value, k) {
    if(isDateFlag)
    {
         var defaultValue = value.auction_id;
         grpArray.push(value.title);
         var postData = {
             parent_id : parent_id,
             defaultValue : defaultValue,
             isDateFlag : isDateFlag,
             search_text : search_text
         }
         getChildNotificationList(postData, function (childArrayData) {
            //Creating the response array

             responseArr.push({
                'notification_id' : childArrayData['notification_id'], 
                'notification_text' : childArrayData['notification_text']
             });
        });

     }
});

return responseArr;//Blank Array
```

I want to return the final responseArr after manipulating it from child data query. It  return blank array because it does not wait for the query response.

So how it can be async. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You should use `async.map` instead of `each`. And you need to call `k`.

Comment: http://justinklemm.com/node-js-async-tutorial/ here is a neat example which you can follow... @Bergi: why async.map()?? why new array?

Comment: @Thalaivar: Because you don't need `responseArr.push` with `map`

Comment: @Bergi: how? you would need it... its something he is doing with is inner function some logic or params he is pushing... may be his code is not clearer for me to understand...

Comment: @Thalaivar ... Thanks for the helpful tutorial. It works fine in the callback :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I referred http://justinklemm.com/node-js-async-tutorial/ and https://github.com/caolan/async.

This happens because the control goes on executing the code since javascript is synchronous. For getting the expected result modify the code as below:

```
var responseArr = new Array();
async.each(response, function (value, k) {
  if(isDateFlag){
    var defaultValue = value.auction_id;
    grpArray.push(value.title);
    var postData = {
      parent_id : parent_id,
      defaultValue : defaultValue,
      isDateFlag : isDateFlag,
      search_text : search_text
    }
    getChildNotificationList(postData, function (childArrayData) {
      //Creating the response array

      responseArr.push({
        'notification_id' : childArrayData['notification_id'], 
        'notification_text' : childArrayData['notification_text']
      });
      k();
    });
  } else {
    k();
  }
}, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    return responseArr;
  }
});
```

The above code is inside a function block. You could get the result by calling the function.

**Including the answer using async.map**:

```
async.map(response, function (value, k) {
  if(isDateFlag){
    var defaultValue = value.auction_id;
    grpArray.push(value.title);
    var postData = {
      parent_id : parent_id,
      defaultValue : defaultValue,
      isDateFlag : isDateFlag,
      search_text : search_text
    }
    getChildNotificationList(postData, function (childArrayData) {

      k(null, {
        'notification_id' : childArrayData['notification_id'], 
        'notification_text' : childArrayData['notification_text']
      });
    });
  } else {
    k(null, {
      'notification_id' : '', 
      'notification_text' : ''
    });
  }
}, function(err, results){
  // results is now an array
  return results;
});
```

Comment: It will always return array until the loop is going on.... I need to send it once after the all the child data pushed into the main response Array

Comment: I think you should specify that in your question by providing a proper code example. I have answered for the question you posted. You haven't mentioned about the looping. :)

Comment: code is starting with the async.each loop.. no need to mention it for the technical  guys.

Comment: `k != callback`, and you should rather use `async.map` instead. Also none of your three `return`s make any sense. And you must not forget to call `k` in case `isDateFlag` is not set.